# swift 3 my array is empty even after I've added values to it

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm currently working with swift 3 in order to create an application and I'm stumbling across a problem. Basically, what is happening is in my function, I add values to an array in a block and I print out the array and it seems fine, but when I exit the block, the array is the same as how I declared it globally.
This is my code..search for the comments to know where I append and print the array:

```
class listUsers: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [""]
var userIDs = [""]
var isFollowing = ["" : true]

//My array declared globally
var theArray = [1]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }else if let users = objects {
            self.usernames.removeAll()
            self.userIDs.removeAll()
            self.isFollowing.removeAll()

           //Notice here How i remove all the elements from my array so that it's empty
            self.check.removeAll()
            for object in users {
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                    self.userIDs.append(user.objectId!)

                    let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
                    query.whereKey("Follower", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId)!)
                    query.whereKey("Following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

                    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                        if let objects = objects {

                            if objects.count > 0 {

                                self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true
                                self.theArray.append(5)
                                //This prints out [5,5..]..the number of 5 is dependent on the for loop.
                                print(self.theArray)


                            }else{
                                self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                            }

                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    //But when I reprint it here, it prints out [1] and I don't know how to fix it
    print(theArray)

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    print(theArray)

    return cell
}
```

So in the cellForRowAt function when I print theArray, it prints it out as [1] a few times and than empty and than it prints it out with the actual numbers in it properly. But that's a problem since I only did that to debug but I will be user it to index and I'd need the actual values.

Any help would be great, thanks! (Also this piece of code simply queries through a table in a server but I believe what the rest of it is not that relevant to this question since elements are 100 percent being added to the array)

Comment: `findObjectsInBackground` <- name says that it is an async task which means code reaches the last `print(theArray)` immediately. If that method is really doing async operation then you should have seen the `[1]` before `[5, 5...]` in the console.

Comment: The closure `query.findObjectsInBackground` is asynchronous. So I'm guessing you are trying to troubleshoot threads. My question is what thread does print(theArray) get invoked?

Comment: Okay I understand that it is asynchronous so it makes sense that [1] gets printed...I'm guessing it'd be fine if i printed it in another function

Comment: Please see edits @user3124081

Comment: Try this. After where you say: `self.theArray.append(5) //This prints out [5,5..]..the number of 5 is dependent on the for loop.print(self.theArray)` try this code: `DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in  self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: I tried it, it didn't seem to work. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I figured it out...

I just had to delete the:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

That was near the end of the viewDidLoad function